# Failure to load hardware monitor driver - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I have installed a new version of windows 10 (RS 2). When I try to install my motherboard (msi) drivers via DVD I get "Failure to load hardware monitor driver" error.

In older versions of windows 10 I did not have this problem.
I installed graphics drivers and also monitor driver! But the same problem exists.

How to solve it?

Comment: Windows 10 Creators update is a new Windows, so wait for an update

Comment: Please clarify: Windows 10 RC2 or RS2? RC2 is the release candidate 2. (It has expired years ago.) RS2 is the latest version as of today, Redstone 2.

Comment: @FleetCommand Yes you're right, it is RS2.

Comment: I always have this kind of trouble with ASUS motherboards. Did you try the compatibility settings?

Comment: @FleetCommand Yes I Did. But No Success...